# differences in caper berry seeds

Tags: salad, seeds

I use caper berries in salad sometimes, but honestly I mainly like to just eat them straight out of the jar. I've noticed that in a single jar, each berry has 1 of three types of seeds inside:

Black seeds, which are hard in texture

Red seeds, which are also hard, but maybe slightly harder (or softer?) than the black ones

White seeds, which are much softer than the other two.

It seems odd that in a single jar, all 3 varieties would persist. Does the color of the seed indicate anything about the berry? Is there a taste or age difference?

Comment: See also: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/50140/fried-capers-and-caper-alternatives/50141#50141

Comment: Many plants do go through phases like this for seed maturation -- starting off small, white or clear and soft, then getting larger, harder and colored, then finishing off dark brown or black. (e.g. apple or watermelon seeds)

Answer (score 1):

forgive me for asking, but are your capers perhaps in a jar with peppercorns? [image: pepper colours]

if so, this might explain it

sadly i'm not an expert on this plant, but they might be like other flowers (a sweetpea for example comes in several colours)

oh-- i will not post a pic because someone will take points from me, but as you love capers it might interest you to know that they grow on **the Western Wall** in Jerusalem :)

if your caper habit becomes too expensive you might try [Pickling Dandelion Buds](http://scandinavianfood.about.com/od/saucesrelishespickles/r/Pickled-Dandelion-Bud-Capers.htm) & [Nasturtium Buds](http://homecooking.about.com/od/condimentrecipes/r/blcon121.htm)

Comment: I think _caper berries_ and _capers_ are different stages of the same plant, and the _berries_ would have seeds inside (while capers, the delicious pickled buds, would not).